# How do we Move SSRS Snapshot Data from one server to another?

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I have a requirement to move SSRS Snapshot data from one report server to another.  I found a way to export the snapshots using PowerShell, but I do not see a way to import the data from there.

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
This SQL statement shows the snapshot data, but it appears that the data is being streamed into a BLOB in the Segment table.

select * from [dbo].[SnapshotData] SD
    join dbo.History H
      on h.SnapshotDataID = sd.SnapshotDataID
    join dbo.Catalog C
      on c.ItemID = h.ReportID
    join dbo.SegmentedChunk SC
      on SC.SnapshotDataId = SD.SnapshotDataID
    join dbo.ChunkSegmentMapping CSM
      on csm.ChunkId = sc.ChunkId
    join dbo.Segment S
      on s.SegmentId = csm.SegmentId
where 1=1
order by 
 c.Path 
, sd.CreatedDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have there is what you need.  the data is in segment.content.

swap out the reportid in history with the reportid on the new server.

in order load:
history (with the new reportid)
snapshotdata (just goes without alteration)
segmentedchunck (dont load the int segmentedchunkid its an identity)
chunksegmentmapping (just goes)
segment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).